# Who is speaking here?

Tags: colonization, colonial-america

Our English teacher gave us an exercise to do: We got different texts what people *could have said* and our task now is to find out: Who said it and when?

Our current topic is "The early years of the US", so I think it should be between 1750 and 1770. But I really have no idea what this text could refer to. I already found out 5/6 of the texts, but I can't solve this one. Can you give me a hint, please?

Cite: 
*Have you heard about* **it** *yet? Five people! No wonder everyone is angry!*

Could it be one of the British colonists? But why is he so angry? And who could this "five people" be?

P.S.: Yes, this is a homework question, sorry. The thing is, I really have no idea and also already had a look at the book if I could find any information, but that's not the case.

Comment: Clearly they're talking about a specific, major event.  In this case during the leadup to the war.

Comment: A Hint? King Street.

Comment: It's most probably about the [Boston Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Massacre), in which five people were killed.

Comment: @JMVanPelt THANK you SO much! I also finally found it in our book, it's a quick mention we didn't read in the lesson. But thank you. Do you want to make an answer?

Comment: I should actually have just given a hint as the previous commenters did. As you found it on your own anyway, I posted the answer but made it a community wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most probably about the [Boston Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Massacre), in which five people were killed.